# css property DISPLAY not giving the desired output

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have assigned class to 4 div elements on the page and all of them are set to display = none now i want to change that to display block when another div on the page is clicked . I have successfully managed to 
 1. hide all the elements onload
 2. use javascript to change the display property to block when a different div element is clicked

the problem is that it show the content full width just like it actually is but instead it shows up in one column overlapping all of it and in one straight column i dont know why this is happening  and i will appreciate the help.

javascript code:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(id){
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
  for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
   elements[i].style.display = elements[i].id == id ? ' inline' : 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

This code is working fine guys please help me figure out how to have it display properly when someone clicks on cooking& recipes, beverages , explore and restaurants . Link to the page : http://theinformant.to/food-drink/

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the site is using `isotope` (http://isotope.metafizzy.co) for the grid layout. Toggling the `display` property, unfortunately, does not cause `isotope` to recalculate the display positions of the elements.

Since you hid the elements on load, when `isotope` gets initialized, it cannot determine the size of each element as it is not in the document flow due to `display: none`, hence when shown, it just gets stacked on top of each other. You will also notice that when you resize the viewport, the elements get properly laid out. This is because `isotope` listens for a window resize event and automatically calls it's `layout()` method.

So the solution to this is when you change your elements to `display: block` you also have to call `isotope`'s `layout()` method (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#layout).

Comment: Thank You so much . There was no way i could have guessed it. I am new to programming and i really appriciate your help. I am not using jquery but i am using javascript. On the page that you mention i found : 

// jQuery
$grid.isotope('layout')
// vanilla JS
iso.layout()
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 50
  }
});
// change size of item by toggling gigante class
$grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('gigante');
  // trigger layout after item size changes
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});

What should i use out of this ?

Comment: Well since you're using a pre-made WordPress theme, it seems as though they are already using `jQuery` and have used it to initialise `isotope`. So it would be easiest if you just use `jQuery('.isotope').isotope('layout');` which essentially looks for the `div` with the class `.isotope` (the one that contains all your posts on that page) and calls `isotope`'s `layout` method on it.

Comment: so in a script tag i should write :
jQuery('.isotope').isotope('layout');
??

Comment: Add it to your function above, after showing the elements.

Comment: Like so:
    `<script>
      function myFunction(id){
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
          elements[i].style.display = elements[i].id == id ? ' inline' : 'none';
        }

        jQuery('.isotope').isotope('layout');
      }
    </script>`

Comment: I am having issues with the page again. When you click on cooking & recipes or beverages you will see categories and you need to click on them to show the content but the content should show by default. I have left a copy of the cooking and recipe section as you can see the content is visible by default. under "all" section, the post is visible in the grid format. but if you click on the beverages and see the category show up &you will have to click to show the post. How can I solve this please help

Comment: Seems like the same issue as I have previously stated. Use `jQuery('.fusion-portfolio-wrapper').isotope('layout');` to call relayout on the `.fusion-portfolio-wrapper` container which contains the items in each category. It appears as though the `isotope` has again been used to layout those items.